# Parallel execution in testNG using Maven

Tags: multithreading, selenium, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, testng

My scenario is to launch multiple chrome browsers(minimum 2) in Parallel.

I have created a separate class for WebDriver initialization, also I have 2 xml files and in that file it has 2 tests each.

**WebDriver Initialization**

```
 public class LaunchBrowser
 {
   public WebDriver driver;

   public WebDriver initDriver() {

    if (driver == null) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    return driver;
   }
}
```

**XML file 1 : test method 1**

```
public class Stackoverflow extends LaunchBrowser
{
  @Test
  public void 1test() throws InterruptedException
  {
     initDriver();
     driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     System.out.println("Stack");
  } 

  @Test
  public void 2test() throws InterruptedException
  {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
  }
}
```

**XML file 1 : Test method 2**

```
public class StackLogin extends LaunchBrowser
{
   @Test
   public void 1test() throws InterruptedException
   {   
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?
ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
   }

   @Test
   public void 2test() throws InterruptedException
   {
      Thread.sleep(3000);
   }

}
```

**XML file 2 : Test method 1**

```
public class Google extends LaunchBrowser
{
  @Test
  public void 1test() throws InterruptedException 
  {
     initDriver();
     driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     System.out.println("Google");
  }

  @Test
  public void 2test() throws InterruptedException
  {
   Thread.sleep(3000);
  }
}
```

**XML file 2 : Test Method 2**

```
public class Gmail extends LaunchBrowser
{
   @Test
   public void 1test() throws InterruptedException
   {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm'][text()='Gmail']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
   }

   @Test
   public void 2test() throws InterruptedException
   {
     Thread.sleep(3000);
   }
}
```

**testng1.xml**

```
<suite name="Suite1">
  <test name="01Stackoverflow">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ci.selenium.Stackoverflow" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="02StackLogin">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ci.selenium.StackLogin" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

**testng2.xml**

```
<suite name="Suite2">
  <test name="1Google">
     <classes>
        <class name="com.ci.selenium.Google"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="2Gmail">
    <classes>
       <class name="com.ci.selenium.Gmail"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Also I have made the below configurations in my **pom.xml** file

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <suiteXmlFiles>${file}</suiteXmlFiles>
               <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                  <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                        <value>2</value>
                    </property>
                  </properties>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Finally I have triggered the XML file using the below maven command.

```
mvn clean test -Dfile=MyWork/testng1.xml,MyWork/testng2.xml
```

**Result:**

Two Chrome browsers were launched at a time, but only first test method in each xml file got passed and the second test in both xml files gets failed.

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

**Logs**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ci.selenium.StackLogin.1test(StackLogin.java:12)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
... Removed 18 stack frames
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have launched multiple(minimum 2) chrome browsers in Parallel by using the below site.

[Thread Local for Parallel Test Execution](http://seleniumautomationhelper.blogspot.in/2014/02/initializing-webdriver-object-as-thread.html)

To achieve this scenario, I have created 3 classes. One for WebDriver initialization and other classes for Threads.

**Class 1**

```
public class SetTestNG implements Runnable
{
  public String xmlString;

  public SetTestNG(String suitXMLUrl){
    xmlString = suitXMLUrl;
  }

  @Override
   public void run(){
     List<String> testSuites = Lists.newArrayList();
     testSuites.add(xmlString);
     TestNG testng = new TestNG();
     testng.setTestSuites(testSuites);
     testng.run();
   }
}
```

**Class 2 : Main Class**

```
public class MultiThread
{
    private static String inputFiles;

   private static String[] xmlFile;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, InterruptedException
   {

      inputFiles = args[0];
      xmlFile = inputFiles.split(",");

      for(String file : xmlFile)
      {
        Thread object1 = new Thread(new SetTestNG(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+file));
        object1.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      }
   }

}
```

**Note:** The main use case of this code to launch Chrome browser for every single testNG Suite files.

Answer (score 0):

You again need to initilize driver in your second Test method of both class

```
 public class LaunchBrowser
 {
   public WebDriver driver =null;

   public WebDriver initDriver() {

    if (driver == null) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    return driver;
   }
}
```

XML file 1 : Test method 2

```
public class StackLogin extends LaunchBrowser
{
   @Test
   public void 1test() throws InterruptedException
   {   
initDriver();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?
ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
   }

   @Test
   public void 2test() throws InterruptedException
   {
      Thread.sleep(3000);
   }

}
```

XML file 2 : Test Method 2

```
public class Gmail extends LaunchBrowser
{


@Test
   public void 1test() throws InterruptedException
   {
    initDriver();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm'][text()='Gmail']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
   }

   @Test
   public void 2test() throws InterruptedException
   {
     Thread.sleep(3000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ankur, I have already tried the above steps, results was, 2 browsers were launched in parallel and first test in each xml's file gets executed and after that 2 browsers were launched for next test in each xml's file, and gets failed.

Comment: My scenario is to achieve each xml file should have one chrome browser and that should execute all the test methods. In my case, I have 2 xml files, so 2 chrome browsers should get launch in that 1 for testng1.xml and another for testng2.xml.

Comment: If I initialize the webdriver in all classes, then there will be no continuation between test1 and test2 methods in single xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want your webdriver instance to be created only once per `<suite>` tag and then shared across `@Test` annotated test methods that reside amongst multiple `<test>` tags.

For achieving this, you would need to change your `LaunchBrowser` class to something like below :

```java
public class LaunchBrowser {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite
    public void initDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

You also need to refactor all your tests, so that they don't explicitly call `LaunchBrowser.initDriver()` else, it would cause the webdriver instantiation to be happened twice - explicitly by your call and implicitly once by TestNG due to the method being annotated using a `@BeforeSuite` annotation.

That should solve your use case. But please remember that this is the most in-efficient way of managing your webdriver instance, because you are now strictly confined to sequential execution. You cannot run tests in parallel.